# Struct from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a project which uses a library which was mostly build on and around C++.
The delivered DLL with this library, i have imported into my C# project.
After importing the following method in Unity:

```
    [DllImport("pst")]
private static extern int pst_get_sensor(PSTSensor sensor);
```

I require this PSTSensor struct, so actually use the method.
In the C++ .h file, the struct is defines as :

```
struct PSTSensor
{
        char    name[80];       /**< Device name */
        int     id;             /**< Device identifier (for other tracking interfaces */
        float   pose[16];       /**< Device pose estimate as row-major matrix */
        double  timestamp;      /**< Time the data was recorded */
};
```

I have tried to replicate it in C#, and i ended up with this following:

```
    struct PSTSensor{
    PSTSensor(char[] name, int id, float[] pose, double timestamp){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.pose = pose;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public char[] name;
    public int id;
    public float[] pose;
    public double timestamp;
}
```

In the example C++ code that came with this project was stated to call `pst_get_sensor(&sensor)` this '&' sign, i do not recognize? How would i call this method in C#, and make it work?

I think i ruined the struct, seeing how i never worked with them before. At least it doesn't throw errors on compilation anymore, but i think it is still wrong. Any ideas on that?

Many thanks in advance,
Smiley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm answering your question entirely, but in c++ the & is used to pass an argument by reference which means that the argument you're passing in can be manipulated inside the function. To me it looks like the original function is used to fill out a sensor struct.

int C# you can pass by reference with the ref or out keyword:

```
private static extern int pst_get_sensor(PSTSensor ref sensor);
```

Why did you add a constructor in your C# implementation?

Comment: This is a great help already, i added a constructor because i was not sure how to define the arrays in a fixed size without it. I tried different ways which mostly just threw errors at me.

Comment: 'private static extern int pst_get_sensor(PSTSensor ref sensor);' This gives the error: Identifier expected, 'ref' is a keyword.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think the ref keyword is actually supposed to come first: (ref PSTSensor sensor). Check out the C# reference, maybe it will help you to gain more understanding of passing by reference in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: Yep, that seems to fix it just right! Do you have any idea on the proper use of the structs? I can't find a lot of good examples on it yet.

Comment: what do you mean by "the proper use of structs?"

Comment: Well, i now use a struct with a constructor, the C++ example is what it should be like. I have a feeling that mine is over complicated (also, using a struct crashes my software, calling pst_get_sensor(PSTSensor ref sensor);

Comment: Structs are usually used when you need to have a set of related values encapsulated in one place, for example a Point with X and Y values or a struct with contact information (name, email, phone number, address) and so on. When you need methods, events and such types members there's nothing wrong using a struct, but when these types of members are required it's more common to make the type a **class** instead because as far as I can remember, the Struct cannot inherit from other Structs.

Comment: The problem is that i need the struct, because the library requires it as input. This is what happens if i remove the constructor btw: http://puu.sh/5pQlj.png

Comment: As I understand you're supposed to create a PSTsensor, pass it in the pst_get_sensor as reference, and the values will be assigned to in the pst_get_sensor function. Have you tried doing this without the constructor?

Comment: Without the struct constructor? Yes i just did. it still crashes the whole developer software (Visual studio / Unity)

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm causing you frustration with all this ;) Have you tried somethig like this to initialize your fields:   struct PSTSensor
    {
        PSTSensor()
        {
            this.name = new char[80];
            this.id = 0;
            this.pose = new float[16];
            this.timestamp = 0;
        }
        public char[] name;
        public int id;
        public float[] pose;
        public double timestamp;
    }

Comment: I have tried it like that, the problem is that it crashes as well. I think however after questioning my teacher, that my problem lies with the C++ Arrays and C# arrays. these are causing mayor issues, since they are nothing alike.

Comment: You are probably right since the c++ function can directly alter your PSTsensor struct. To me it sounded like a problem with uninitialized fields. Take a look at this, looks related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654892/passing-c-sharp-structure-with-string-array-to-c-function-which-accepts-void

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look at it, i will most likely make a new topic about this problem.

Comment: Actually in an expression, as is the case here in the context of an actual parameter, `&` is used to take the address of an object. You've got to be careful of the term reference in C++ because it has a precise and specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that all you need to do is declare the parameter as ref

```
private static extern int pst_get_sensor(ref PSTSensor sensor);
```

If you want to have a look at an example, there is one [here](http://www.nag.com/IndustryArticles/Calling_C_Library_DLLs_from_C_Sharp.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You did not show the C++ declaration of your function, but give that you call it like this:

```
pst_get_sensor(&sensor);
```

it is presumably declared like so:

```
int pst_get_sensor(PSTSensor *sensor);
```

The function receives a pointer to the struct. That is clear since the call uses the `&` operator which takes the address of an object.

On the C# side you translate this parameter as a `ref` parameter. Like this:

```
[DllImport(...)]
static extern int pst_get_sensor(ref PSTSensor sensor);
```

Now, your other problem is that your struct is declared incorrectly. It contains inline arrays and you must communicate the lengths of those arrays to the marshaller. Like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
struct PSTSensor
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
    public string name;
    public int id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public float[] pose;
    public double timestamp;
}
```